# How can I get a line of string from a large block of string?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextpane, indexof

What I'm trying to do is get a segment of a large String. I have tried using indexOf(), but that fails completely when it comes to repeated text. My end goal is for a user to be able to select text in a JTextPane and stylize only that portion of text. I've already gotten the styling to work with StyledDocuments and I've even gotten it to style only text that the user selects but here's my problem.

Let's say that

> String alltext = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

And what the user highlights is `String selectedtext`

In this case, lets just say

> String selectedtext = "brown";

My goal is to get the offset and length of the selected text. For this particular sentence, I can simply do:

```
int offset = alltext.indexOf(selectedtext);
int length = selectedtext.length();
```

And this will work fine. But what if:

> alltext = brownbrownbrownbrownbrown;

And the user highlights the third brown. If I do the same thing as I did previously, the program will just pick the first brown instead of the real one and it will style the first one.

Is there any way around this or alternative to getting the position of a segment of String from a large block?

Thanks!

Comment: there are a few questions about I think that two answers in the related (under Careers 2.0 Icon)

Comment: Why are you tracking the selection as a string, and not directly as an index/offset as is commonly done? A JTextPane should do that automatically. Or, to put it differently: if for some reason you can only determine what string the user is looking for, there's no way to know which one it is.

Comment: How exactly do you get the index value from a JTextPane? Is there a method that does that for you?

Comment: I'm guessing [`getSelectionStart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectionStart()) and [`getSelectionEnd()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectionEnd())

Comment: Thank, getSelectionStart() seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's a UI problem, not a java.lang.String problem.

If you post your UI code, we may answer well.

With Swing, the TextComponent and the underlaying model may help, giving you the [start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectionStart%28%29) and the [end](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectionEnd%28%29) indices of the current selection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. If you're saying you want to detect when a user has selected text and then stylize that text:

In order for someone to select text, they have to click on the text area, drag and release the click. So, attach a MouseListener and implement the mouseReleased method to check if any text was selected, and if so to save it as a string:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (textArea.getSelectedText != null){ //see if they selected something 
        String s = textArea.getSelectedText();
        //stylize s
        }
```

EDIT: If you're going to use a button, then its even easier. Add an ActionListener to the button and

```
     public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (textArea.getSelectedText() != null){ //see if they selected something 
        Font f = showStyleOptionsMenu();
        textArea.getSelectedText().setFont(f);
        }
```

`showStyleOptionsMenu()` displays a new panel (or dialog or whatever) that lets the user choose the font style, then returns the font chosen to the listener, which applies it to the selected text.

Comment: please modelToView / viewToModel (Document / AbstractDocument)

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: Or you could just use a [`CaretListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#addCaretListener(javax.swing.event.CaretListener)) instead of hacking this using mouse events

Comment: How can I stylize s in the mouseReleased method when the user is supposed to press a JButton in a separate class to determine the styling?

Comment: @millimoose agreed for JTextArea without html, special and whitespace chars e.g. ...